# Android Http Get Request

Tags: java, android, http

I'm a newbie at android development. I'm trying to send a GET request to an URL. I wrote the below code.

```
public void searchProducts(View v) 
{
    //String txtSearchTerm = ((EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtsearch)).getText().toString();
    //String termCleaned = txtSearchTerm.replace(' ', '+').toString();
    AlertDialog alertMessage = new AlertDialog.Builder(this).create();
    alertMessage.setTitle("Loading");
    alertMessage.setMessage(GET("http://webkarinca.com/sample.json"));
    alertMessage.show(); 
} 
public static String GET(String url){
    InputStream inputStream = null;
    String result = "";
    try {

        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpResponse httpResponse = httpclient.execute(new HttpGet(url));
        inputStream = httpResponse.getEntity().getContent();
        if(inputStream != null)
        {
            result = convertInputStreamToString(inputStream);
        }
        else
        {
            result = "Did not work!";
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.d("InputStream", e.getLocalizedMessage());
    }

    return result;
}
private static String convertInputStreamToString(InputStream inputStream) throws IOException{
    BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader( new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
    String line = "";
    String result = "";
    while((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null)
        result += line;

    inputStream.close();
    return result;

}
```

I already put imports head of the class. There they are

```
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.json.JSONObject;
```

It doesn't work and at the Problems section it shows as a warning

The type HttpGet is deprecated
The type HttpResponse is deprecated

Comment: Did you log the output of the variable json ? Is it a json object? what is the exception? please provide the logcat output.

Comment: Before the parse operation the data doesn't come from URL. I'm having the problem at getting data step.

Comment: What is the error in logcat?

Comment: I just updated the code. The output of this code is.
[Screen](http://puu.sh/gNlSa/7341e91b8c.png)

Comment: Have you tried my code?

Comment: I did but it didn't work and I put some screenshot above.

Comment: have you added the    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" /> line in your android manifest file?

Answer (score 1):

Try this. it worked for me.

**first must implement this on** `build.gradle: app`

```
    implementation("com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:4.8.0")
```

**then, use this method**

```
    String run(String url) throws IOException {
        OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
        Request request = new Request.Builder()
                .url(url)
                .build();

        try (Response response = client.newCall(request).execute()) {
            return response.body().string();
        }
    }
```

Finally, call it on `onCreate method`

```
run("enter your URL here");
```

Comment: avoid posting an answer to the old question. 2015 Gradle syntax by the time would have been different.

Comment: thanks for your advice, I will try to avoid this. @learner

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.SocketTimeoutException;
import java.net.URL;

import android.content.Context;

import com.jivebird.settings.CommonMethods;

public class Connecttoget {

    public static String callJson(Context context,String urlstring){

        String data=null;

        try {
            URL url = new URL(urlstring);
            HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

            conn.setReadTimeout(10000 /* milliseconds */);
            conn.setConnectTimeout(15000 /* milliseconds */);
            conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
            conn.setDoInput(true);
            // Starts the query
            conn.connect();
         InputStream stream = conn.getInputStream();

      data = convertStreamToString(stream);


         stream.close();

         }catch(SocketTimeoutException e){

             CommonMethods.createAlert(context, "Sorry, network error", "");
         }
        catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
         }

        return data;

    }

    static String convertStreamToString(java.io.InputStream is) {
          java.util.Scanner s = new java.util.Scanner(is).useDelimiter("\\A");
          return s.hasNext() ? s.next() : "";
       }

}
```

Comment: I did few changes on method but it didn't work.
[link](http://pastebin.com/5FBM6r6H)

Comment: u tried my code?and is it not working?please post the code and your error log along with the url you are using are you sure that the url you are using recieves data in getmethod?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try the below code,if it helps.

```
  HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
    URL url = null;
    JSONObject object = null;
    InputStream inStream = null;
    try {
        url = new URL(urlString.toString());
        urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
        urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);
        urlConnection.setDoInput(true);
        urlConnection.connect();
        inStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();
        BufferedReader bReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inStream));
        String temp, response = "";
        while ((temp = bReader.readLine()) != null) {
            response += temp;
        }
        object = (JSONObject) new JSONTokener(response).nextValue();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        this.mException = e;
    } finally {
        if (inStream != null) {
            try {
                // this will close the bReader as well
                inStream.close();
            } catch (IOException ignored) {
            }
        }
        if (urlConnection != null) {
            urlConnection.disconnect();
        }
    }
```

Comment: I changed your code to a single web request method but it didn't work. Here it is [link](http://pastebin.com/Ma1TpaKM)

Comment: Can you tell me please what error message  you are getting.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code. This worked for me.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.params.HttpConnectionParams;
import org.apache.http.params.HttpParams;
import org.apache.http.protocol.HTTP;
import org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;


public class ServerTest extends Activity {

    private String TAG = "test";
    private String url = "http://webkarinca.com/sample.json";


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        new Download().execute();
    }


    public class Download extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String>{

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
            String out = null;

            try {
                DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();

                final HttpParams httpParameters = httpClient.getParams();

                HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpParameters, 15000);
                HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpParameters, 15000);

                HttpGet httpPost = new HttpGet(url);

                HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
                HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();

                out = EntityUtils.toString(httpEntity, HTTP.UTF_8);

            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return out;
        }


        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            Log.e(TAG, result);
        }
    }
}
```

Also make sure you have added this to manifest,

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

and also make sure you are connected to the internet.