# How to get a part of an URL content

Tags: java, android, html, url, android-studio

I wan't to display a part of an HTML page, but I only find how to get a source code of an HTML page when I search a solution: [How to get the html-source of a page from a html link in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2423498/how-to-get-the-html-source-of-a-page-from-a-html-link-in-android)

```
HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpGet request = new HttpGet(url);
HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);

String html = "";
InputStream in = response.getEntity().getContent();
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();
String line = null;
while((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
{
    str.append(line);
}
in.close();
html = str.toString();
```

But if I do that, how can I get a part of the page, and the solution is too old. I've found an another solution named webview, but I don't know what is the best solution to display a part of a html page and how to do it.

EDIT:
This page: http://www.solutis.fr/groupe-solutis,mentions-legales.html

Without tag, header, footer, only the content of body without tag too.

Comment: which part do you need ? only the text without tags or what?

Comment: @GabriellaAngelova This page: http://www.solutis.fr/groupe-solutis,mentions-legales.html

Without tag, header, footer, only the content of body without tag too.

Comment: Try with JSOUP. You can find tutorials for that from google.

Comment: @SumighoshCharuvil Ok im gonna do some search about this

Answer (score 1):

What you need is one more line - when you become the HttpResponse it is the whole html from the response site, so you need to remove all tags from it and you could do this with a single line

```
String responseAsText = android.text.Html.fromHtml(html).toString();
```

where html is your string with the repsonse from the HttpResponse.

Comment: But if i use the prévious code i get deprecated elements like HttpClient, HttpGet, HttpResponse

Comment: no matter how you get your content of a html page, you can use the line above, but when you don't want to use HttpClient and so on, you could use HttpEntity - take a look here - second provided code fragment from the question's author http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29936731/how-to-get-only-string-from-httpresponse-restapi-android/29937176#29937176

Comment: I don't understand, you're saying that with this line
String responseAsText = android.text.Html.fromHtml(html).toString();
I can get the content of my page ?

Comment: no, you can get it as you want (for example with HttpEntity like in the link I provided you in the comment) and then you can use this line to extract only the text content from the page, without the tags

Comment: EntityUtils is deprecated, android change a lot, so a lot of tutorial are deprecated, hod to do with EntityUtils ? Android.com say use:  openConnection() but how ?

Comment: Try with this code:
`DefaultHttpClient client = new MyHttpClient(getApplicationContext());`
`HttpGet get = new HttpGet("http://www.solutis.fr/groupe-solutis,mentions-legales.html");`
`// Execute the GET call and obtain the response`
`HttpResponse getResponse = client.execute(get);`
`HttpEntity responseEntity = getResponse.getEntity();`
`// Retrieve a String from the response entity`
`String content = EntityUtils.toString(responseEntity);` or something like this - try to Google it http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9679673/how-do-i-use-the-command-httpentity

Comment: I dont see where he put the url here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29936731/how-to-get-only-string-from-httpresponse-restapi-android/29937176#29937176 in public String readResponse(HttpResponse res)

Comment: the url is set to the HttpGet or HttpPost, the code is from the response above

Comment: I have to use the two codes ? Its hard to nderstand now... I don't see how to implement in my onCreateView

Comment: this is the whole code http://pastebin.com/rG7eha7s you should write in your onCreateView

Comment: defaulthttpclient httpGet httpResponse and httpentity are deprecated, i think its because i use API 14 no ?

Comment: hmmmm another possible solution is to use HttpUrlConnection or OkHttp

Comment: Its look hard i was looking here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29225654/android-http-get-request
But the modifications to do looks hard to me, i think theyre a better solution like JSOUP...

Comment: try with JSOUP if you want, another HTTP library is Volley https://developer.android.com/training/volley/index.html

Comment: What is for you the simplest solution using API 14 ?

Comment: maybe the volley library something like this http://pastebin.com/FE83ztak of course with your url